# How can I tell the proper dosage of Selenium Yeast for a young pig?

Tags: health, medicines

I have some Selenium Yeast to feed to my pigs and help solve deficiencies. But it doesn't come with instructions on how much I should give them. How can I tell the proper dosage for the pigs and how should I administer it to them?

Comment: @Zaralynda Related to [this question](http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/6022/481)